# Phalcon: recive action parametrs with a question mark OR how to get variables from GET method

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, routes, phalcon

I have to recive information from another server (token) with http GET method.
I can change URL at witch I get I it, so I figured I could try to get the GET to be a parameter in an action like this:

```
start/tokenize/token?code=doekoedjorcfoehof
```

And it turns out that evrything after '?' is ignored.
Also I tried to define a route:

```
$di->getRouter()->add("/tokenize?code={code}", "Start::tokenize");
```

So that is ignored as well...

I think '?' has something to do with apache mod_rewrite, is it possible to retrive a GET with a special mod_rewrite rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Router component is not able to route from the query string, it only parses the route uri:

```
start/tokenize/token?code=doekoedjorcfoehof
```

A route for that URL is the following:

```
$di['router'] = function() {

    $router = new Phalcon\Mvc\Router(false);

    $router->add('/start/tokenize/token', array(
        'controller' => 'tokenize',
        'action' => 'parse'
    ));

    return $router;
};
```

In your controller:

```
<?php

class TokenizeController extends Phalcon\Mvc\Controller
{
    public function parseAction()
    {
        $code = $this->request->getQuery('code');
    }
}
```